# Sphinx for writing "parallel text"

Tags: restructuredtext, python-sphinx, design-decisions

Problem: I am trying to write "parallel text" using [reStructuredText](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html).  By "parallel text", I mean something like annotated works of fiction, where the text is in two columns.  The left column contains the main text, and the right column contains commentary.  I will be using [sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/) for generating HTML and Latex documentation from it.

I have the following requirements:

1. As mentioned above, I should be able to typeset text in two columns, one for the main text and one for the annotations.
2. The annotations can be "sentence level", and will not always be "paragraph level".  I.e., I want to be able to annotate different sentences in a paragraph, or the whole paragraph.
3. It will be great to have a mode where all the annotations are turned off, so the output HTML and Latex only contains the main text.  In this case, I would like to be able to use the whole "real estate" of the medium, rather than just a column.
4. It will be very nice to have a "list of annotations" feature if possible.

I am pretty new to reStructuredText and to Sphinx, but have considerable experience with Python.  I am looking for some ideas about how to do what I want to do.  I have been reading about reStructuredText and also about writing Sphinx extensions, so writing an extension to Sphinx is not out of question.

Has anyone done something similar before?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you use tables? http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#tables

Then you might be able to somehow change the table cell borders and cell margins to get what you want.  Might have to do some sort of customized CSS file..

Comment: Ross, that's an interesting idea.  I will try that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

These seem very similar to footnotes? I would suggest having a look at http://ignorethecode.net/blog/2010/04/20/footnotes/

If they suit your purpose, integrating them should not be too difficult. Sphinx outputs footnotes with a special class. Replacing the

$("a[rel='footnote']")

in the code, with a jquery css selector of your choice should give you what you desire.

Comment: I like this idea.  One problem is that since there are going to be a *lot* of annotations, the main text will have a lot of footnotes.  I also want to be able to see all the annotations in context.  The `sidebar` directive is probably what I need, but the problem is that the sidebar is floating, so it's not guaranteed to be visibly associated with the main text.  Thanks!

Comment: But the links between the footnote and the annotation will probably provide enough cohesion. Additionally, the fixed-two-column approach will have problems no matter what if the amount of text and annotations is not equivalent and proportional, and all annotations are visable. Playing with the visability of the annotations with JavaScript might be useful.